# Pandas: insert a number for the unique value in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID':['27637', '27637', '27637', '27637', '89283', '89283', '89283', '89283'],
'Country':['UK', 'Poland', 'Poland', 'Poland', 'China', 'China', 'India', 'India']})
```

I added an additional column by
`df['Dense_Rank'] = df.groupby('ID')['Country'].rank(method='dense')`

However, I don't like group 27637 as UK is marked as 2.0 while Poland 1.0. As UK appears first, I expect it to be marked as 1.0 while Poland as 2.0. Grouping for 89283 looks good.

Here is my expected result:

| ID | Country | Dense_Rank | Expected_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27637 | UK | 2.0 | 1.0 |
| 27637 | Poland | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 27637 | Poland | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 27637 | Poland | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 89283 | China | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 89283 | China | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 89283 | India | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 89283 | India | 2.0 | 2.0 |

Comment: i can't understand what u want can u explain more

Answer (score 1):

One option, is to use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) :

```
df['Expected_Result'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Country'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      ID Country  Dense_Rank  Expected_Result
0  27637      UK         2.0                1
1  27637  Poland         1.0                2
2  27637  Poland         1.0                2
3  27637  Poland         1.0                2
4  89283   China         1.0                1
5  89283   China         1.0                1
6  89283   India         2.0                2
7  89283   India         2.0                2
```